# Django admin static css not found with heroku foreman start locally...but pushed remote is fine

Tags: heroku, django-admin, foreman

When I run **foreman start** locally - I do not get the admin css loading from static...

but when its pushed remote its all working as expected!  doh.

I want my local foreman to mimic my remote instance...

heres my current settings.py for static stuffs:  ( can someone help? )

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static'),
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [Serving Static Files in Development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development) at the Django documentation for static files. It shows how to make Django serve the static files using your python app server.

Answer (score 6):

Try modifying your STATIC_ROOT to let say project_path/static/ and run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Heroku automatically runs collectstatic (if everything is set up correctly) :)

Hope it help!

Answer (score 1):

Add to *settings.py* in your project:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Then add to *wsgi.py* in your project:

```
from dj_static import Cling
application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

Answer (score 0):

First, @Evgeny answer was a right answer. Following the link will get you the answer. But, I missed his answer at first because he didn't inline the relevant part. So, I just want to inline an option (with slightly differently solution than his -- two birds in one stone) here:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # your other urls
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```